# Adding polyines to polylines to create a complex itinerary

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is it possible to add `polylines` to existing `polylines` using `leaflet` without modifying the lib? If so how should I go about doing it?

[image: leaflet multi polylines]

In the image above you can see two polylines that seem connected, but in reality they are not. The ideal solution would be that the point of intersection would actually be a shared point of both polylines.

I've thoroughly looked through the leaflet documentation and all existing plugins, and it seems this functionality does not yet exist.

I've thought about creating my own plugin, but how should I structure it? I thought about creating a "multiple itinerary handler" to handle all "connected" polylines. This would be heavy though with all the layers there could be?

Comment: That's called snapping. I've never used it before in Leaflet, but this plugin might offer the functionality that you desire, check out the demo:
https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Snap

Comment: @AlexandruPufan Thanks for the link. It gets really close to what I want. I suppose it could work.